# how to run multiple instances of asterisk on one server

Tags: unix, asterisk, voip

hope everybody is safe during challenging time

i have a task to automate our demo installation process.
Our software is mainly a GUI that operates with asterisk via AGI and stores all data to MySQL / MariaDB storing all sip configuration , and CDR logs
for each potential costumer we have to setup a separate virtual server

the key task is to find a solution to connect multiple instances of our software to a single asterisk instance since it’s a demo server there is usually 1-5 simultaneous calls max
main question is there a way to include a different config files depending on the connection ip.
eg: we have over 128 IPS mapped to the server each demo server will have a dedicated ip to map did’s and to whitelist for the sip trunking ( to avoid fraud ) if some device is connecting to a dedicated ip corresponding res_mysql , cdr_mysql , and sip config files are loaded.

maybe there are other different ways to solve this task?

any advices are welcome

thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could run it as a container. I have run asterisk from numerous openvz containers.  Its far easier on resources sharing ram cpu.

It would not be exactly a single asterisk instance but how openvz shares things

It can be done as long as its not too busy it should be able to handle per your resources.